# How to cancel ngxs dispatch actions

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

How to cancel a running `store.dispatch(xxx)` action, so that the underlying http requests are canceled as well?

I tried to `.unsubscribe()` from a `store.dispatch(new FetchSomeStuffOverHttp())` call and expected that the underlying http request is also canceled.

But it will continue to run, even if the `httpClient`'s observable is returned by the action:

```
@Action(FetchStuffOverHttp)
fetchStuffOverHttp({ patchState }: StateContext<AuftragStateModel>) {
  return this.httpClient.get(...)
                        .pipe(
                            tap((...) => {  patchState(...) })
                         )
}
```

Is it the expected behaviour that `store.dispatch(xxx).subscribe().unsubscribe()` is not unsubscribing/canceling the `httpClient`s observable?

In contrast, the `{ cancelUncompleted: true }` option will cancel the underling http request.

Answer (score 2):

Q: How to cancel a running store.dispatch(xxx) action, so that the underlying http requests are canceled as well?

A: If the underlying http request is within an observable chain returned by the action (i.e. an async action), then dispatching same action with `{ cancelUncompleted: true }` will cancel the previously dispatch action if it is still running.

If you want to cancel a running async action without dispatching to it again, you will have to deal it from the action's observable yourself (e.g. using appropriate rxjs patterns like the `takeUntil()` operator).

Q: Is it the expected behaviour that store.dispatch(xxx).subscribe().unsubscribe() is not unsubscribing/canceling the httpClients observable?

A: Yes. AFAIK, this is by design & expected behavior.

Comment: Thx for the answer. We used `takeWhile` now. But `takeUntil()` and `takeWhile()` won't cancel the running http call. So doesn't solve the whole problem :/